# Notation clarification in fibre bundles

Tags: fiber-bundles

I am trying to comprehend the following material, I have some doubts mostly regarding the notations.

> **Chern Classes:**
> Throughout this section, we will use $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients and let $\xi=(E, X, \pi)$ denote a $d$ 'dimensional vector bundle with total space $E$, base space $X$ and projection $\pi$. We also use $E^{\#}$ to denote $E \backslash s_0(X)$, where $s_0: X \rightarrow E$ is the zero section.
> In the case where $\xi$ admits a $\mathbb{Z}$-orientation $\left\{\varepsilon_x\right\}_{x \in X}$, recall that there is a unique class $u_{\xi} \in H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right)$ (the Thom class) which restricts to $\varepsilon_x$ on each fibre. The Euler class $e(\xi) \in H^d(X)$ is then defined by the image of $u_{\xi}$ under the composition
> $$
> H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right) \longrightarrow H^d(E) \stackrel{s_0^*}{\sim} H^d(X) .
> $$
> This has the property that, if $\xi^{\prime}=\left(E^{\prime}, X^{\prime}, \pi^{\prime}\right)$ is another oriented $d$-dimensional real vector bundle and $(F, f): \xi \rightarrow \xi^{\prime}$ is an orientation-preserving bundle morphism, then $f^* e\left(\xi^{\prime}\right)=e(\xi)$. We say that $e$ satisfies the naturality condition.

Please let me know what are following

1. $\left\{\varepsilon_x\right\}_{x \in X}$, particularly what are the values $\varepsilon$ can take here
2. In here $H^d\left(E, E^{\#}\right)$ the cohomology $H^d$ takes two arguments,  while in here $H^d(E) $ there is only one argument, so what are these spaces with regards to the cohomology.

In here, I assume the following correct, if not, please correct me.

1. $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient means the coefficients are integers
2. $E \backslash s_0(X)$ means the set $E$ with the zero section removed
3. $s_0^*$ stands for the pull back of the zero section map $s_0$

Comment: Don't delete questions like that, it's extremely annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $\pi : E \to X$ be a real rank $d$ vector bundle and let $E_x := \pi^{-1}(x)$ be the fiber of $E$ over $x$. A $\mathbb{Z}$*-orientation* on $E$ is a choice of generator $\varepsilon_x$ of $H^d(E_x, E_x\setminus \{s_0(x)\}; \mathbb{Z})$ for every $x \in X$ such that for each $x \in X$, there is an open set $U \subseteq X$ and a cohomology class $u \in H^d(\pi^{-1}(U), \pi^{-1}(U)\setminus s_0(U);\mathbb{Z})$ with the property that $u|_{E_x} = \varepsilon_x$ for all $x \in U$. A good reference for this material is Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes* (for this specific question, chapter $9$).
2. Here $H^d(E, E^{\#})$ is a relative cohomology group. There is a map of pairs $(E, \emptyset) \to (E, E^{\#})$, so there is an induced map of relative cohomology groups $H^d(E, E^{\#}) \to H^d(E, \emptyset) = H^d(E)$.

The three statements at the end of your post are correct.

Comment: what is the significance of the $E^\#$ with respect to orientation. I am thinking in analogy with a mobius strip bundle, in that case removing the zero section amounts to cut the mobius in the middle which would make the mobius with two twists. A twice twisted mobius is orientable I guess.

Comment: For an $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$, a generator of $H^n(V, V\setminus\{0\}; \mathbb{Z})$ can be viewed as an orientation on $V$; see page $96$ of Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*. Note that $E^{\#}$ is the union of $E_x\setminus\{s_0(x)\} = E_x\setminus\{0_x\}$ for every $x \in X$, where $0_x$ denotes the zero vector in $E_x$.

Comment: I am getting to your point, but still confused on how is that a generator of $H^n(V,V^\#) $ can be viewed as an orientation of $V$.